# Barras "/" e espaço em branco em parâmetros de funções Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: erro na passagem de parametro]

Preciso passar uma string que contém barras e espaço em branco.

```
<a href="javascript:carregaCliente('184/5 RB')"></a>
```

E na função

```
function carregaCliente(reg){

        console.log(reg);

        var map;

        $('#modalMapa').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            map = new GMaps({
                div: '#map',
                center:{
                    lat: latitude,
                    lng: longitude
                },
                zoom: 17,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                },
                styles: [{
                    "featureType": "poi",
                    "stylers": [
                    { "visibility": "off" }]
                }]
            });

            map.addMarker({
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude,
                infoWindow: {
                    content: '<div style="padding-top:8px;color:#333;"><p>Cod Cliente: '+reg+'</p></div>'                   
                },
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            }); 
            var markerInstance = map.markers[0];
            markerInstance.infoWindow.open(map, markerInstance);
        });         
    };
```

Simplesmente nao carrega a página.
o mesmo acontece se coloco uma data ex: 10/01/2016 14:00:50

Comment: uê, não vejo nada demais na sua função, veja funcionando no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtgq900q/

Comment: Mostre como chega seu parâmetro na função.

Comment: Tb não detectei o problema. Usar barra / dentro de um parâmetro string não influencia em nada. Já se fosse contra-barra \ a história seria outra.

Comment: @GabrielHeguedusch editei a pergunta com a foto

Comment: Ta bom, melhor então, posta a sua função de carregar o cliente.

Comment: Pela foto dá pra identificar o problema. A string está sendo passada pra função carregar sem estar entre aspas.

Comment: No código que você postou `<a href="javascript:carregaCliente('184/5 RB')"></a>` está mostrando com as aspas simples ('..') - `'184/5 RB'`, porém, no teu print está mostrando sem, será que não ta faltando no teu código original?

Comment: coloquei a função @AntonioAlexandre

Comment: @EzequielTavares abre o código fonte da sua página e verifica se o código gerado no seu link está mesmo assim <a href="javascript:carregaCliente('184/5 RB')">algoclicavel</a> ou se está assim:
<a href="javascript:carregaCliente(184/5 RB)">algoclicavel</a> (sem as aspas simples em volta de 184/5 RB). Se tiver sem as aspas simples encapsulando a string o problema é esse. Números podem ser passados sem aspas, strings não.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre está sem as aspas o parametro. tens razao mas na verdade corrigi o codigo e continua a nao passar o parametro. no meu caso eu fiz com uma string mas esse codigo do cliente ira vir dinamicamente atraves de uma variavel php

Comment: Faça o teu código do lado servidor gerar com aspas simples e passe para os próximos problemas, haha

Comment: Se tiver vindo do lado do servidor você deve colocar assim: `<a href="javascript:carregaCliente('<?php echo $variavel; ?>')">texto</a>`

Answer (score -1):

Espaços em branco como parâmetros são problemáticos. Procure substituir o espaço em branco pelo seu equivalente em UTF-8: `\u0020`

Comment: Oi Vlademiro! Podes acrescentar código à tua resposta para ficar mais completa?